# ngModel Overwrites the previous value while using in ng-For

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel, ngmodel

This is my html file

```
<form [formGroup]='itemUpdateForm'>
      <div class="row">
        <mat-form-field class="col-sm-8">
            <mat-label>Restaurant Name:</mat-label>
            <input matInput type="text" required  [(ngModel)]="this.restuarantService.selectedProduct.name"   placeholder="Enter Restaurant Name" formControlName='name'>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>

      <div class="row" *ngFor='let index of counter(this.restuarantService.selectedProduct.Items.length) ;let i = index' formGroupName='Items'>
        <mat-form-field class="col-sm-5">
          <mat-label>Food Name:</mat-label>          
          <input matInput type="text" required  [(ngModel)]='this.restuarantService.selectedProduct.Items[i].foodName'   placeholder="Enter Food Name" formControlName='foodName'>
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field class="col-sm-5" >
        <mat-label>Price:</mat-label>
        <input matInput type="text" required  [(ngModel)]="this.restuarantService.selectedProduct.Items[i].price"   placeholder="Enter Price" formControlName='price'>
      </mat-form-field>
      </div>
      
    </form>
```

And My Output looks like this
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCwB2.png)

The Last value overwrites the previous values in all the fields. So I'm getting the last value in all the fields..I want to display all the values in order.What change i need to do

Comment: Why are you using both formcontrolname and ngmodel? Kindly share more code for better understanding

Comment: How to bind those values in reactive Form?Like Two Way Binding

Comment: Share a working example (stackblitz)

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uiiets?file=src/restuarantService.service.ts

Just check the output

Comment: @VenkateshPrasath, if you use Reactive Form use setValue, https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#setvalue or pathValue https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#patchvalue or give value when create the formGroup https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#usage-notes, **not** use [(ngModel)]

Comment: @Eliseo can u check the link and tell me what to change https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uiiets?file=src/Restuarants.ts

Comment: @VenkateshPrasath, see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Venkatesh, you has a type error. If you use formBuilder, is

```
this.formBuilder.group({
 name: this.restuarantService.selectedProduct.name
 ...
})
```

If you use the constructors of FormGroup and FromControl you use

```
new FormGroup({
 name: new FormControl({value:this.restuarantService.selectedProduct.name})
 ...
})
```

or

```
new FormGroup({
 name: new FormControl(this.restuarantService.selectedProduct.name)
 ...
})
```

Well the another problem in your code is that you need use a FormArray for the "items", see e.g. [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67700663/how-to-using-a-formarray-in-a-formgroup/67701198#67701198)

**UPDATE** see that it's always the same

1.- create a getter that return the formArray

```
  get itemsArray()
  {
    return this.itemUpdateForm.get('Items') as FormArray
  }
```

2.-Create an auxiliar function that allow us to create a formGroup

```
  createGroupItem(data:any=null)
  {
    data=data || {foodName:'',price:0}
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      foodName:data.foodName,
      price:data.price
    })
  }
```

Before the setValue you need add so many elements to the formArray as the "items"

```
setValue() {
    //before setValue, to a FormArray you need that the 
    //formArray has as many element as the data
    this.restuarantService.selectedProduct.Items.forEach(
          x=>this.itemsArray.push(this.createGroupItem()))

    //if the object not match exactly with the object use patchValue, not setValue
    //see how we pass the "Items", simply indicate the items
    this.itemUpdateForm.patchValue({
      name: this.restuarantService.selectedProduct.name,
      Items: this.restuarantService.selectedProduct.Items
    });
  }
```

The .html

```
<!--a div with formArrayName-->
<div formArrayName="Items">
    <!--iterating over the formArray.controls using the getter
        and use [formGroupName] -->
    <div *ngFor="let control of itemsArray.controls;let i=index"
            [formGroupName]="i">

        <!--the inputs with formControlName, see that in this case 
            is not enclosed by []-->
        <input formControlName="foodName">
        <input formControlName="price">
    
    </div>
</div>
```

Your [forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jswpy1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) with the changes

NOTE: Really I like create also a new function that return the formGroup fully

```
createGroup(data:any=null)
{
   data=data ||{name:'',Items:null)
   return this.formBuilder.group({
        name:data.name,
        Items:data.items?this.formBuilder.array(
               items.map(x=>this.createGroupItem(x)):
       this.formBuilder.array([])
   })
}
```

And in ngOnInit()

```
itemUpdateForm=this.createGroup(his.restuarantService.selectedProduct)
```

Comment: How can i use this for an Array of Objects?

Comment: I updated the answer again. I hope this help you

Comment: NOTE: I just add to my answer a new function to create the formGroup