# Add form array after scann a barcode

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli

I'm trying to add a formArray after scann a barcode to a formGroup. the result that i get is a json, I have the connection and the method to create the form array (or I believe that). I'm using Angular 12

Here is how I declare my form group

```
kanbanPedidoForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    usuario: ['', Validators.required],
    fecha: ['', Validators.required],
    ruta: ['', Validators.required],
    estacion: ['', Validators.required],
    folio: ['', Validators.required],
    material_guid: this.formBuilder.array([]),
})
```

then when I active the camera of the cellphone or in my case the laptop camera and I scann the barcode I make a server petition

```
SearchKanban(){
    // this.AddDetails();
    this.cargandoInformacion = true;
    this.despachadoresService.getScannedKanban(this.barcodeValue).subscribe(
        response => {
            this.kanbanBusquedaForm.reset();
            if(response.status == 'success'){
                this.tablaKanban = true;
                this.cargandoInformacion = false;
                this.kanbanInfo = response.kanban;
                this.kanbanNombre = response.kanban[0].kanban_nombre
                this.materiales = JSON.parse(response.material)
                this.infoMaterial = this.materiales[0].material_guid

                
            }
        },
        error => {
            console.log(<any>error);
        }
    )
}
```

then I create the form array

```
get details(){
    return this.kanbanPedidoForm.get('material_guid') as FormArray;
}

AddDetails(){
    const detailsFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      id: this.getNewId(),
      material: '',
      unidad_medida: '',
      descripcion: '',
      minimo: '',
      maximo: '',
      requerido: ''
    });
    this.details.push(detailsFormGroup);
}
```

this is what I get in the response

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0:
id: 1
material_guid:
active: "Y"
created_at: "2021-05-28T13:27:03.000000Z"
deleted_at: null
descripcion: "Descripcion 1"
material_guid: "ddef30f4-d1cd-4547-ae5e-d150e854e280"
nombre: "Material 1"
unidad_medida: "UM 1"
updated_at: "2021-05-28T13:27:03.000000Z"
__proto__: Object
maximo: 3
minimo: 1
__proto__: Object
1: {id: 2, material_guid: {…}, minimo: 1, maximo: 2}
```

And in my HTML I have a table where i want to fill it with the data of my json

```
<form [formGroup]="kanbanPedidoForm" *ngIf="tablaKanban">
  <table class="table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col" colspan="6">Usuario: {{despachadorName}}</th>
        <th scope="col" colspan="1">Fecha: {{myDate | date: 'shortDate' }}</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col" colspan="2">Ruta: {{rutaName}}</th>
        <th scope="col" colspan="2">Estación: {{kanbanNombre}}</th>
        <th scope="col" colspan="2">No. Req: {{folio}}</th>
        <th scope="col" colspan="2">
          <a mdbBtn size="sm" gradient="blue" mdbWavesEffect>
            <mdb-icon fas icon="save"></mdb-icon>
          </a>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Material</th>
        <th scope="col">Descripción</th>
        <th scope="col">UM</th>
        <th scope="col">Minimo</th>
        <th scope="col">Maximo</th>
        <th scope="col">Requerido</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr formArrayName="material_guid" *ngFor="let material of materiales; index as i;">
        <td [formGroupName]="i">
          <input class="requiredQty" type="text" [attr.id]="'material' + i" formControlName='material' placeholder="Material">
        </td>
        <td [formGroupName]="i">
          <input class="requiredQty" type="text" [attr.id]="'descripcion' + i" formControlName='descripcion' placeholder="Descripcion">
        </td>
        <td [formGroupName]="i">
          <input class="requiredQty" type="text" [attr.id]="'unidad_medida' + i" formControlName='unidad_medida' placeholder="Unidad de medida">
        </td>
        <td [formGroupName]="i">
          <input class="requiredQty" type="text" [attr.id]="'minimo' + i" formControlName='minimo' placeholder="Minimo">
        </td>
        <td [formGroupName]="i">
          <input class="requiredQty" type="text" [attr.id]="'minimo' + i" formControlName='minimo' placeholder="Minimo">
        </td>
        <td [formGroupName]="i">
          <input class="requiredQty" type="text" [attr.id]="'maximo' + i" formControlName='maximo' placeholder="Maximo">
        </td>
        <td [formGroupName]="i">
          <input type="number" class="requiredQty" name="" formControlName='requerido' [attr.id]="'cantidad' + i">
        </td>
      </tr>
      
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)="AddDetails()">
    <i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    Agregar concepto
  </button>
</form>
```

hope someone can helpme I get stuked since 2 days

Comment: take a look to this SO:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67700663/how-to-using-a-formarray-in-a-formgroup/67701198#67701198. When you need use a *ngFor without create an "html tag" (in your case you're using a table, so you can use ng-container:https://angular.io/guide/built-in-directives#ngcontainer)

Comment: I try with that, I forgot a point... when I scann the barcode, I need to send how many things I'm going to send if you can see, in the formArray I've a field "requerido" here I need to saw if I require 1 or 3 dinamically with some buttons

Answer (score 0):

More step by step.

Create a function that return a formGroup better that add the data in the FormArray

```
groupDetails(data:any=null){
  data=data ||{id: this.getNewId(),material: '',unidad_medida: '',
               descripcion: '',minimo: '',maximo: '',requerido: ''
    };
     return this.formBuilder.group({
      id: data.id,
      material: data.material,
      unidad_medida: data.unidad_medida,
      descripcion: data.descripcion,
      minimo: data.minimo,
      maximo: data.maximo,
      requerido: data.requerido
    });
}
```

Your .html should iterate over the FormArray.controls, forget the "materials"

Your .html should be like

```
<tbody>
   <!--see that you first say the formArrayName, use a ng-container
        to not create extra tags-->
    <ng-container formArrayName="material_guid">

      <!--the *ngFor in the "tr", see that also include the formGroupName-->
      <tr *ngFor="let group of details.controls; index as i;" 
             [formGroupName]="i">

        <!--in each td your input with formControlName-->
        <td >
          <input class="requiredQty" type="text" [attr.id]="'material' + i" formControlName='material' placeholder="Material">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="requiredQty" type="text" [attr.id]="'descripcion' + i" formControlName='descripcion' placeholder="Descripcion">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="requiredQty" type="text" [attr.id]="'unidad_medida' + i" formControlName='unidad_medida' placeholder="Unidad de medida">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="requiredQty" type="text" [attr.id]="'minimo' + i" formControlName='minimo' placeholder="Minimo">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="requiredQty" type="text" [attr.id]="'minimo' + i" formControlName='minimo' placeholder="Minimo">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="requiredQty" type="text" [attr.id]="'maximo' + i" formControlName='maximo' placeholder="Maximo">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" class="requiredQty" name="" formControlName='requerido' [attr.id]="'cantidad' + i">
        </td>
      </tr>
   </ng-container>
</tbody>
```

Well, we are going to "feed" the formArray. If you received in response the array you can use

```
this.despachadoresService.getScannedKanban(this.barcodeValue)
   .subscribe(
        response => {
          //I imagine the json you show is really the response.material
          //Angular by defect received json objet
          //so I think that is not neccesary your JSON.parse, 
          //but really I'm not pretty sure -else use Json.parse(response.material).map(...)-
          this.details=new FormArray(response.material.map(x=>this.groupDetails(x)))
        })
```

See that we transform the array in response using map. Each element of the array response convert in a formGroup -using the function this.groupDetails- and we say that details is a FromArray with the array of formGroup-

Well really there'e a problem, your json not has the property "material" nor "requerido" if requerido is a new property change a bit the function groupDetails, some like

```
groupDetails(data:any=null){
  //e.g.
  //If you use material_guid and not material
  //and requerido is true by defect.

  data=data ||{id: this.getNewId(),material_guid: '',unidad_medida: '',
               descripcion: '',minimo: '',maximo: ''
    };
     return this.formBuilder.group({
      id: data.id,
      material: data.material_guid, //<--see how use material_guid
      unidad_medida: data.unidad_medida,
      descripcion: data.descripcion,
      minimo: data.minimo,
      maximo: data.maximo,
      requerido: 0 //<--see how I wrote a value "ad hoc"
    });
}
```

NOTE: See that if you want to add a new line in the table you can add a button and a function

```
addGroup(){
   this.details.push(this.groupDetails());
}
```

Or remove a line

```
removeLine(index){
   this.details.removeAt(index)
}
```

Comment: How do I need to declare this.details? if I declare as how i've in my question, this trowme error and if i remove the ``get`` in ``details`` show me other error

Comment: try check if exist before:`get details(){return this.kanbanPedidoForm.?this.kanbanPedidoForm.get('material_guid') as FormArray:null}` and use a *ngIf to not show the table if is null