# submit array of objects using reactive forms in angular 8

Tags: angular

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, FormArray, Validators, FormControl } from '@angular/forms'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-employee',
  templateUrl: './employee.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employee.component.css']
})
export class EmployeeComponent implements OnInit {

  employeeForm!: FormGroup;
  locations: Array<string>= ['Pune', 'Hyderabad', 'Noida']; 
  skills:  Array<ChoiceClass> = [
    {description: 'descr1', value: 'value1'},
    {description: "descr2", value: 'value2'},
    {description: "descr3", value: 'value3'}
  ];
  mat: MatrixDTO[] = [];
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initilazieForm();
    this.employeeForm.get('matrix')!.setValue(this.createBaseMatrix())
  }

  
  initilazieForm(): void {
    this.employeeForm = this.fb.group({
      name: 'Name here',
      gender: ['male', [Validators.required]],
      location: '',
      notes: '',
      email: '',
      skills: this.fb.array([], [Validators.required]),    
      matrix: this.fb.array([], [Validators.required]),  
      references: this.fb.array([this.fb.control('')])
    });
  }
  onSubmit(): void {
    console.log(this.employeeForm.value);

  }
  selectLocation(event:any):void{
    this.employeeForm.patchValue({
      location:event.target.value
    });
  }
  addEmail(): void {
    this.references.push(this.fb.control(''));
  }
  removeEmail(index: number): void {
    this.references.removeAt(index);
  }

  get references(): FormArray {
    return this.employeeForm.get('references') as FormArray;
  }

  onCheckboxChange(e:any) {
    const website: FormArray = this.employeeForm.get('skills') as FormArray;
  
    if (e.target.checked) {
      website.push(new FormControl(e.target.value));
    } else {
       const index = website.controls.findIndex(x => x.value === e.target.value);
       website.removeAt(index);
    }
  }

  createBaseMatrix(): MatrixDTO[] {
    this.mat[this.mat.length] = new MatrixDTO();
    this.mat[0].name = "Basic Weight(lbs/3000ft)";
    this.mat[0].customRow=false;
    this.mat[0].items.push({label:'30', customCol:false});
    this.mat[0].items.push({label:'35', customCol:false});
    this.mat[0].items.push({label:'40', customCol:false});
    
    
    this.mat[this.mat.length] = new MatrixDTO();
    this.mat[1] = new MatrixDTO();
    this.mat[1].name = "Basic Weight(g/m2)";
    this.mat[1].customRow=false;
    this.mat[1].items.push({label:'34', customCol:false});
    this.mat[1].items.push({label:'42', customCol:false});
    this.mat[1].items.push({label:'68', customCol:false});
    
    
    console.log(this.mat);
    return this.mat;
  }
  
}


export class MatrixDTO implements cols {
  constructor() {    
    this.name = "";
    this.items = [];   
    this.customRow = false;     
     this.label="";
     this.customCol=false;
  }
  name : string;
  items :Array<cols>;
  customRow:boolean;
  label: string;
  customCol:boolean;
  
}


interface cols {
  label: string;
  customCol:boolean;
}

export class ProductDTO {
  constructor() {
    this.id = "";
    this.name = "";     
  }

  id : string;
  name: string;
}

export class ChoiceClass {
  constructor() {
    this.description = "";
    this.value = "";     
  }

  description : string;
  value: string;
}
```

and also HTML is as follow for this one :

```
 <p>employee works!</p>
<form [formGroup]="employeeForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
 <label>
     Name : 
     <input type="text" formControlName="name" placeholder="required"/>
 </label>

 <label>
    Location : 
    <select formControlName="location" (change)="selectLocation($event)">
        <option *ngFor="let loc of locations" [value]="loc">
                {{loc}}
        </option>
    </select>
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" value="Male" formControlName="gender">
    <span>male</span>
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" value="Female" formControlName="gender">
    <span>female</span>
</label>
<h2>Please select what skill you're comfortable working with, if any:</h2>
<label for="website">Website:</label>
<div *ngFor="let skill of skills">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" [value]="skill.value" (change)="onCheckboxChange($event)" />
    {{skill.description}}
  </label>
</div>

  <h2>Reference(s)</h2>
  <div formArrayName="references" class="grouping" *ngFor="let ref of references.controls; let i=index">
    <label>
      Reference Email: 
      <input type="text" placeholder="optional" [formControlName]="i">
      <button type="button" id="remove_email"(click)="removeEmail(i)">X</button>
    </label>
  </div>
  <button type="button" (click)="addEmail()">Add Another Reference</button>
    <button id="apply_button">Save</button>
</form>
```

** How can I pass the matrix array of objects on submit in reactive forms ? and also How I can setup same information when user come on same screen for edit**

**Edited One :
after applying suggestions from one of answer now I am getting following error :**

[image: Console Error]

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-msrnn1?file=src/app/app.module.ts)

Comment: Can you provide the createBaseMatrix method and how you are setting the controls on HTML?

Comment: edited with more information

Comment: two links, in SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67700663/how-to-using-a-formarray-in-a-formgroup/67701198#67701198, from the great Netanel Basal:https://netbasal.com/angular-reactive-forms-the-ultimate-guide-to-formarray-3adbe6b0b61a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 Quick things to keep in mind:

1. If you want the value of a reactive form, `form.value` will not give you what you want. You may want to use this:

```
const formValue = this.form.getRawValue();
console.log("Form Value ==>", formValue);
```

2. If you want to add things to a form-control, in the method `createBaseMatrix()`, you are mentioning that the return type of that method is `createBaseMatrix(): void {}`, which means you are not returning anything. Hence the value is null in your case.

To correct this: Change the return type of that method, and make sure you are returning something and then assign to the formControl by doing this:

```
createBaseMatrix(): yourReturnType {}

this.form.get('matrix').setValue(this.createBaseMatrix())

// You can use, setValue or patchValue if you are doing it outside the form.
```

Comment: I tried it but its throwing error in console and still Matrix is null

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-msrnn1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: I made some small edits to that stackblitz. The matrix is not null now. You can see the values there
Link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ck2mxm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: What in case I make changes from UI to this.mat and i want those changes also need to be updated in form matrix control ?

Comment: Thats a whole different issue. Try to create a new question for that. Also, I dont see a formControl with matrix name in the HTML. I am not sure how you are planning on changing this.mat. Generally, you would have to write a valueChanges for matrix formControl and if there are any valueChanges, you will have to either call the same function that you calling to initially update the values or a new function depending on what the need is.

Comment: Okay I am changing the stackblitz and will share the URL , thanks for your time and yes this question is solved .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68007154/changes-in-model-through-ui-not-reflect-in-the-form-values-in-reactive-forms another question with StackBlitz and earlier your intitzaton I dont know why but showing for first matrix[0] values two times. I checked in your stackblizt console. so instead of method return I initialize with the this.mat