# changes in model through UI not reflect in the Form values in reactive forms

Tags: angular

I  am using reactive forms and I have one text box and other item in form is matrix , which is basically array of objects.

Initilazation of form is done using following code :

```
initilazieForm(): void {
    this.specForm = this.fb.group({
      name: 'Enter specsheet name',
      matrix: this.fb.array(this.mat, [Validators.required])
    });
  }
```

and this.mat is as following

```
createBaseMatrix(): MatrixDTO[] {
    this.mat[this.mat.length] = new MatrixDTO();
    this.mat[0].name = 'Basic Weight(lbs/3000ft)';
    this.mat[0].customRow = false;
    this.mat[0].items.push({ label: '30', customCol: false });
    this.mat[0].items.push({ label: '35', customCol: false });
    this.mat[0].items.push({ label: '40', customCol: false });

    this.mat[this.mat.length] = new MatrixDTO();
    this.mat[1] = new MatrixDTO();
    this.mat[1].name = 'Basic Weight(g/m2)';
    this.mat[1].customRow = false;
    this.mat[1].items.push({ label: '34', customCol: false });
    this.mat[1].items.push({ label: '42', customCol: false });
    this.mat[1].items.push({ label: '68', customCol: false });

    return this.mat;
  }
```

I have two buttons on same form , which are used to insert custom row or columns ( text boxes ) , so that user can enter values.

but when I add custom row and columns , insert data into text boxes for each row or column and submit the forms those values doesn't reflect in `this.mat` as well on forms values

```
addRow() {
    console.log('add row clicked');
    this.mat[this.mat.length] = new MatrixDTO();
    this.mat[this.mat.length - 1].name = '';
    this.mat[this.mat.length - 1].customRow = true;
    let colsCount: number = this.mat[0].items.length;
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < colsCount; i++) {
      this.mat[this.mat.length - 1].items.push({ label: '', customCol: true });
    }
    console.log(this.mat);
  }
  addColumn() {
    this.mat.forEach(x => x.items.push({ label: '', customCol: true }));
    console.log('add column clicked');
    console.log(this.mat);
  } 



<form [formGroup]="specForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm()">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-9">
        <label for="name">Enter specsheet name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter specsheet name" formControlName="name" id="name">

      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">
        <a (click)="addRow()">Insert Custom
          Row</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
        <a (click)="addColumn()">Insert
          Custom Column</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div *ngFor="let row of mat" class="row">
          <div class="col-3">
            <span *ngIf="row.customRow===false">{{row.name}}</span>
            <input *ngIf="row.customRow==true"
                                        type="text" [value]="row.name">
          </div>
          <div *ngFor="let cols of row.items" class="col-1">
            <span *ngIf="cols.customCol===false"
                                        style="padding: 5px;">{{cols.label}}</span>
            <input *ngIf="cols.customCol===true"
                                        type="text" [value]="cols.label"
                                        class="numtext">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

[StackBLitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-4-starter-5c3vae?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: I might be missing something in your code - but a formArray should contains formControl’s..?

Comment: are you talking about this line ?  matrix: this.fb.array(this.mat, [Validators.required])

Comment: Yes.. this.mat is not an array of formControls..right..?

Comment: No , this is array of object with that I initialize , sorry I am new to angular so not much idea , can you please check StackBlizt mentioned in question

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray

Comment: Yes you should not have a regular array of objects inside a FormArray. 

A FormArray should contain an array of FormControls and the single formControl holding this array will act as parent formGroup. Its more like a formGroup inside a formGroup concept. And as per your previous StackBlitz, try to use the method rather than adding an initialized value.

Comment: but using that method showing 6 items in mat[0], instead of 3 items.

Comment: @Mikeone Can you help me with the idea of  how Matrix form field should be setup so add new row or column can work and values can be find in forms.values ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to stay with form logic, I would recommend creating a custom control for matrix presentation and use ControlValueAccessor. In the new component, you can manage data via ngModel and return the result to the parent form. [Example.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-4-starter-oshhen?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

P.S: there's a lot of room to optimizing code example, it was made fast to show logic, not a final clean solution. Cheers.