# can't use map function on undefined , return from subscribe , service data delayed and till that by time map function get executed

Tags: angular

I am using angular to get the data from service

```
  getspecProductAssignment(ProductID:string, ID : string):Observable<any[]>{
    return this.http.get<any>(this.APIUrl+'/SpecAssignment?product='+ProductID+'&id='+ID);
  }
```

and in my .ts page I am using this as follow and successfully able to log the data as well :

```
getspecProductAssignment(ProductID: string, ID: string) : any{
     this.service.getspecProductAssignment(ProductID, ID).subscribe(
       (data:any) => {   
       console.log(data);
       return data.map((x:any)=> ({label:x,customCol:true}));         
    });
  }
```

but when I am using map function as mentioned in above line as I need map function to apply on data , its throw error.

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

[image: error and console output screen]

**I tried with map and pipe operators also with observables but still facing same thing.**

**Edited Version :**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SharedService } from 'src/app/shared.service';
import { MatrixDTO, ReqDTO, SpecAssignDTO } from 'src/app/edit-spec/matrixdto'
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder, Validators, FormArray, RequiredValidator } from '@angular/forms';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { catchError, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit-spec',
  templateUrl: './edit-spec.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edit-spec.component.css']
})
export class EditSpecComponent implements OnInit {

  masterspecs: any = [];
  specs: any = [];
  weightlist: any = [];
  ProductList: any = [];
  selectedProductId: string = "";
  specForm!: FormGroup;
  req: ReqDTO = new ReqDTO();
  items: SpecAssignDTO[];
  isEnablePreview:boolean=true;
  specId :number=0;


  constructor(private service: SharedService, private fb: FormBuilder, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.initilazieForm();
    this.getProductList();

    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
      this.specId = +params.get('id')!;
      if (this.specId>0) {
        this.getSpecDetails(this.specId);
        this.isEnablePreview=false;
      }

    });

  }
  getSpecDetails(specId: number) {
    this.service.getDetailsSpecSheet(specId).subscribe((data: any) => {
      if (data && data.name)      
        this.setFormValues(data);
        this.getSpecsListByProductGroup(data.productName);
    });

  }
  setFormValues(data: any) {
    this.specForm=new FormGroup({
      name:new FormControl(data.name),
      Brand:new FormControl(data.Brand),
      Market:new FormControl(data.Market),
      productName:new FormControl(data.productName),
      IsArchived:new FormControl(data.IsArchived),
      OriginId:new FormControl(data.OriginId),
      IsCustom:new FormControl(data.IsCustom),
      matrix:new FormArray(data.matrix.map(x => this.rowGroup(x))),
    })
    console.log(data);
  }



  initilazieForm(): void {
    this.specForm = this.fb.group({
      name: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      Brand: 'Brand',
      Market: 'Market',
      productName: ['', Validators.required],
      IsArchived: false,
      OriginId: 1,
      IsCustom: false,
      specs: this.fb.array([], [Validators.required]),
      matrix: new FormArray([]),

    });
  }

  submitForm() {

    console.log(this.specForm.value);
    this.req.name = this.specForm.value.name;
    this.req.productName = this.specForm.value.productName;
    this.req.Brand = this.specForm.value.Brand;
    this.req.Market = this.specForm.value.Market;
    this.req.IsArchived = this.specForm.value.IsArchived;
    this.req.IsCustom = this.specForm.value.IsCustom;
    this.req.Matrix = this.specForm.value.matrix;


    this.service.postSpecsheet(JSON.stringify(this.req));
    this.isEnablePreview=false;
  }



  getSpecsListByProductGroup(PG: string): void {
    this.service.getSpecsListByProductGroup(PG).subscribe(data => {
      this.masterspecs = data;

      this.weightlist = this.masterspecs.filter((book: any) => book.name.toUpperCase().indexOf('WEIGHT') > -1);
      this.specs = this.masterspecs.filter((book: any) => book.name.toUpperCase().indexOf('WEIGHT') == -1);

    });
  }

  onPOptionsSelected(value: any) {
    this.getSpecsListByProductGroup(value);
    this.selectedProductId = value;
  }

  getProductList() {
    this.service.getProductList().subscribe(data => {
      this.ProductList = data;
    });
  }

  getspecProductAssignment(ProductID: string, ID: string): void {
    
      this.service.getspecProductAssignment(ProductID, ID).subscribe(
        (data:SpecAssignDTO[]) => { 
          if(data && data.length>0)
          {
            console.log(data);
            this.items= data; 
          }
     }); 
  }


  handleError(e: any): any {
    console.log(e);
  }



  specRowCheck(event: any, id: string) {
    if (event.target.checked) {
      //code to add row to matrix with name   
      

      //const rahul=this.getspecProductAssignment(this.selectedProductId, id);
      
      //const items = this.items.map((x: any) => ({ label: x, customCol: true }))

      const items =[{ label: "10", customCol: true },{ label: "20", customCol: true },{ label: "30", customCol: true }]

      this.addRowSpec(event.target.value, items);
    }
    else {
      //code to remove row from matrix
      //this.mat.splice(this.mat.findIndex(e => e.name === event.target.value), 1);
    }


    const website: FormArray = this.specForm.get('specs') as FormArray;

    if (event.target.checked) {
      website.push(new FormControl(event.target.value));
    } else {
      const index = website.controls.findIndex(x => x.value === event.target.value);
      website.removeAt(index);
    }

  }





  addRowSpec(label: string, items: any) {

    const empty = { label: label, customRow: false, items: items };
    this.matrix.push(this.rowGroup(empty));
  }



  get matrix(): FormArray {
    return this.specForm.get('matrix') as FormArray;
  }


  matrixElement(index: number) {
    return this.matrix.at(index) as FormGroup;
  }
  itemsFormArray(index: number) {
    return this.matrixElement(index).get('items') as FormArray;
  }



  addRow() {
    this.specForm.patchValue({
      IsCustom: true,
    });
    const items =
      this.matrix.length && this.itemsFormArray(0)
        ? this.itemsFormArray(0).value.map((x: any) => null)
        : [{ label: "", customCol: true }, { label: "", customCol: true }, { label: "", customCol: true }];

    const empty = { label: null, customRow: true, items: items };
    this.matrix.push(this.rowGroup(empty));
  }
  addColumn() {

    if (this.matrix.controls.length) {
      this.specForm.patchValue({
        IsCustom: true,
      });
      this.matrix.controls.forEach(x => {
        ((x as FormGroup).get('items') as FormArray).push(this.itemsGroup()
        );
      });
    }
  }
  removeColumn(index: number) {
    if (this.matrix.controls.length > 1) {
      if (index == -1) index = this.itemsFormArray(0).value.length - 1;
      this.matrix.controls.forEach(x => {
        ((x as FormGroup).get('items') as FormArray).removeAt(index);
      });
    }
  }
  removeRow(index: number) {
    this.matrix.removeAt(index);
  }

  rowGroup(data: any = null) {
    return new FormGroup({
      label: new FormControl(data.label),
      customRow: new FormControl(data.customRow),
      items: new FormArray(data.items.map((x: any) => this.itemsGroup(x)))
    });
  }
  itemsGroup(data: any = null) {

    data = data || { label: null, customCol: true }
    return new FormGroup({
      label: new FormControl(data.label),
      customCol: new FormControl(data.customCol),
    })
  }


  weightColCheck(event: any) {

  }

  onPreview(): void {
    console.log("preview button clicked");
    //this.service.previewSpecSheet()
  }





}
```

Comment: `.subscribe` will get executed after `http.get` is completed there is nothing like delay in subscribe, Can you please post more code?

Comment: If your "data" is an array you should use `.subscribe((data:any[]) => {   }` to indicate Angular that is an array

Comment: its still the same error @Eliseo

Comment: @Sameer what part of code more you need ?

Comment: @rahularyansharma I see that you are returning `data.map` in subscribe there is no use when you return data in subscribe, can you post the full code of `edit-spec.component.ts` or create stackblitz.

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: @rahularyansharma, write `console.log(data)` at first, to know what is the data you received

Comment: its an array of objects, [{ label: "10", customCol: true },{ label: "20", customCol: true },{ label: "30", customCol: true }] , the only issue its delayed but @Sameer provided solution worked for me using Promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 3**
There is nothing wrong with using `subscribe`, but you have to call `addRowSpec` in `subscribe` of `getspecProductAssignment` as this method is asynchronous, See the below solution using `subscribe` you will get the idea.

```js
getspecProductAssignment(event: any, ProductID: string, ID: string) {
    this.service.getspecProductAssignment(ProductID, ID).subscribe(items => {
      this.addRowSpec(event.target.value, items);
    })
}

specRowCheck(event: any, id: string) {
  if (event.target.checked) {
    this.getspecProductAssignment(event, this.selectedProductId, id);
  }
}
```

I recommend you to watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jgWnccjXR4I&ab_channel=Academind)

**Update 2**
Change your code like this

```js
getspecProductAssignment(ProductID: string, ID: string) {
    //convert and return observable to promise, so can be use with async/await
    return this.service.getspecProductAssignment(ProductID, ID).toPromise();
}

async specRowCheck(event: any, id: string) {
  //Convert this function to async to use await
  if (event.target.checked) {
    //Await here and do not call "addRowSpec" until data fetched.
    const items = await this.getspecProductAssignment(this.selectedProductId, id);
    this.addRowSpec(event.target.value, items);
  }
  //...All other code removed for readability
}
```

---

I think your error is here, as console pointed `EditSpecComponent.rowGroup`

```js
rowGroup(data: any = null) {
 //Add console.log here for data.items, probably you are getting this as undefined
  console.log(data.items);
  //for a workaround you can assign empty array if its undefined
  data.items = data.items || [];
  return new FormGroup({
    label: new FormControl(data.label),
    customRow: new FormControl(data.customRow),
    items: new FormArray(data.items.map((x: any) => this.itemsGroup(x))) 
  });
}
```

Comment: Error is here because of delay response from API and till by that time undefined is pass to this method.

Comment: I want that till API response get wait for it and then pass only the value which is in response of API  , which is an array of objects similar to what I used in items for now .

Comment: In my posted code I commented out the API call and using static value and its working perfect , the only issue is when I try to get the values from API , because of delay response and async next is executed. //const rahul=this.getspecProductAssignment(this.selectedProductId, id);
      
      
      const items =[{ label: "10", customCol: true },{ label: "20", customCol: true },{ label: "30", customCol: true }]

Comment: @rahularyansharma Answer Updated.

Comment: its working , can you please point out what was wrong when using subscriber method ?

Comment: @rahularyansharma Answer updated again :)