# Reactive forms binding issue

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am using reactive forms and the data on the table is not retrieved properly. it has some binding issue but I don't know where. can someone let me know what the issue here is. the data on the table is getting populated one my one. when I press any bootstrap button it gets triggered and populated data one at a time on a single row based on the click of a button

This is my `activities.component.html`:

```
<div class="page-title w-100">Activities</div>
<div class="action-head justify-content-between d-flex">
    <div class="sub-ptitle"><h6>{{titleService.getTitle()}}</h6></div>
    <div class="act-filter d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
        <input type="text" class="search-filter" placeholder="Search Activities"
            />
    </div>
    <div class="action d-flex justify-content-end">
        <div class="action d-flex justify-content-end">
            <button type="button" class="act-btn thm-btn thm-btn-primary" type="button" (click)="changeText();addFieldValue();saveField()" ion-button> {{ text }}</button>
            <!-- the below button have to be added conditionaly -->
            <!-- <button class="act-btn thm-btn thm-btn-primary" type="button"  (click)="saveField()"><i class="nc-icon nc-check-2"></i> Save</button> -->
        </div>
        <!-- <div class="action d-flex justify-content-end">
            <button (click)="addFieldValue()" [disabled]="projectGroup.invalid">Add</button>
        </div> -->
    </div>
</div>
<br>

<form [formGroup]="projectGroup">
    <div>
            <div>
                <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <div class="table-responsive">
                                        <table class="table">
                                            <thead class="text-primary">
                                                    <th>
                                                        Activity Name 
                                                    </th>
                                                    <th>
                                                        Activity Description 
                                                    </th>
                                                    <th>
                                                      Edit 
                                                    </th>
                                                    <th>
                                                        Delete 
                                                    </th>
                                            </thead>
                                        <ng-container projectGroup.controls.itemRows>
                                         <tbody formArrayName ="itemRows">
                                            <tr *ngFor="let itemrow of itemRows['controls']; let i 
                                                                = index" [formGroupName]="i">
                                                <td class="col-md-2">
                                                    <span *ngIf="!itemrow.editable"> 
                                                   {{itemrow.activityName}}</span>
                                                    <input placeholder="Activity Name" 
                                           formControlName="activityName" *ngIf="itemrow.editable" />
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="col-md-2">
                                                    <span *ngIf="!itemrow.editable"> 
                                           {{itemrow.activityDescription}}</span>
                                                    <input placeholder="Activity Description" 
                                 formControlName="activityDescription" *ngIf="itemrow.editable" />
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="col-md-2">
                                                    <button class="edit" 
                                                   (click)="makeEditable(itemrow)"><img
                                                        src="../../../assets/img/edit.png"
                                                        alt="" /></button>
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="col-md-2">
                                                    <button class="delete" (click)="deleteRow(i)" >
                                                        <img
                                                        src="../../../assets/img/delete.png"
                                                        alt="" />
                                                    </button>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                         </tbody>
                                        </ng-container>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div> 
            </div>
            <pagination-controls (pageChange)="pageChanged($event)"
            [maxSize]="5"></pagination-controls>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is my `activities.component.ts`:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormArray, FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpService } from 'app/_services/http.service';
import { UrlService } from 'app/_services/url.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-activities',
  templateUrl: './activities.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./activities.component.scss']
  
})

export class ActivitiesComponent implements OnInit {
  projectGroup : FormGroup;
  TotalRow : number; 
  userDetails:any;
  public index: any = '';
  public isSubmitted: boolean = false;

  public isVisible : boolean = false;

  public text: string = 'Add Activity';

  config: any;
  collection = { count: 60, data: [] };

  constructor(private _fb:FormBuilder, public titleService: Title,private _http: HttpService,private _url: UrlService) {
    this.projectGroup = this._fb.group({
      itemRows:this._fb.array([]),
    });

    this.getActivityDetails(),

    this.config = {
      itemsPerPage: 5,
      currentPage: 1,
      totalItems: this.collection.count
    };
  }

  get itemRows() : FormArray {

    return this.projectGroup.get("itemRows") as FormArray
  }

  initItemRow():FormGroup{
    return this._fb.group({
      activityName:[""],
      activityDescription:[""],
      enabledFlag: [""]
    })
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.titleService.setTitle("Project Name");
  }

  private getActivityDetails(){
    const url = `${this._url.activity.getActivityList}`
    this._http.get(url).subscribe({
      next:(res:any)=>{
        this.itemRows['controls'] = res.data;
        console.log("data",res.data)
      }
      })
    }

  public changeText(){
    if (this.text === 'Add Activity') {
      this.text = 'save';
    } else {
      this.text = 'Add Activity';
    }
}

makeEditable(itemrow: any) {
  itemrow.editable = !itemrow.editable;
  }

  saveField(){

      if(this.text == "Add Activity"){
      const body = this.itemRows['controls'];
        console.log(body);
      const url = `${this._url.activity.addActivity}`
    this._http.post(url,body).subscribe(
      {
        next:(res:any)=>{
          console.log(res.responseMessage);
        }
      });
    }
  }

public addFieldValue() { 
  if(this.text == "save"){
    this.isVisible = true;
  this.itemRows.push(this.initItemRow());
  }
}

 public deleteRow(index : any) {
  console.log("hiii");
  this.itemRows.removeAt(index)
 }
 
 pageChanged(event){
  this.config.currentPage = event;
}

}
```

Comment: You can **not** use `this.itemRows['controls'] = res.data;` to give value to your FormArray (think that res.data is an array of objects and this.itemsRows['controls'] is an array of FormGroups, so has no sense). You should use the [methods of the formArray](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray) (setValue, insert, pathValue, etc.) You can see, e.g. this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67700663/how-to-using-a-formarray-in-a-formgroup/67701198#67701198) about give value to a FormArray. BTW **not** use some so "bizarro" like this.itemsRows['controls'], just this.itemRow.controls

Comment: @Zakir You are accessing value wrong, Value is binding correctly, you just need to get like this `<span *ngIf="!itemrow.editable"> 
                                                   {{itemrow['controls'].activityName.value}}</span>`

Comment: @hrdkisback Thank you. that works. but the row is getting added on the bottom. can you please tell me how to add it on top of the table?

Comment: @ZakirMemon , well if you want to add it on top you have to iterate loop of formarray   reverse, for that you can do changes and add reverse logic in your component.ts or else you can simple use `reverse()` method in html code ngFor like this `let itemrow of itemRows['controls'].reverse(); let i = index"` but make sure you can use correct index for every elements.

Answer (score 0):

You should go to app.module.ts and then import the following module:

```js
import {ReactiveFormsModule} from "@angular/forms";
```

after that you need to add it to import array like this:

```js
imports: [
    ReactiveFormsModule
],
```