# Angular formarray get formcontrol from custom id

Tags: angular, forms

I'll like to set formControlName of a formArray.  I can't connect the input field with it.

form:

```
this.translationForm = new FormGroup({
  translations: new FormArray([]),
});

this.translations.push(
  new FormControl(de: '' }, [
    Validators.required,
    Validators.min(1),
  ])
);
```

The FormArray looks like that

```
    0: {
       de: ''
    },
    1: {
       en: ''
    }
```

html:

```
    <form
      [formGroup]="translationForm">
        <div formArrayName="translations">
          <div *ngFor="let translation of translations.controls; index as i">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  formControlName="{{ i }}"
                />
          </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: You should write `[formControlName]="i"`, but I imagine you problem is that you has no a "getter": `get translations(){return this.translationForm.get('translations') as FormArray}`. See that it's usual call the function getter equal the formArray name, but it's not necessary. E.g. you can rename your getter for "what-you-want", e.g. `get translationArray(){...}` and replace yours `translations` by `translationArray` (in .html and in the this.translationArray.push())

Comment: in my inputfield i've got [object, object]. When I write smth into the input field, then it overwrites 0: { de: '' } to 0: ''. Thats my problem. I want to write into de and not overwrite the object.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Maybe you should rethink the structure of your form. To me it sounds like you want to have a formgroup with keys like "de", "en" and an associated string to it which will be configurable via inputs.

Comment: Sorry, @RobinFrench, you can to have a FormArray of FormControls or a FormArray of FormGroups, I thought that you have a FormArray of FormControls, but in this case you shouls use `new FormControl('de', [Validators.required,Validators.min(1),])`, see, e.g. this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67700663/how-to-using-a-formarray-in-a-formgroup/67701198#67701198)

Answer (score 0):

The code provided should work. The actual flaw is that you are trying to pass objects to FormControls, instead of plain strings.

Why does your formArray look like:

```
0: {
  de: ''
},
1: {
  en: ''
}
```

when you actually want to edit plain strings via inputs? You should try to just pass a string to the `FormControl` constructor in order to have them editable via inputs:

```
new FormControl("de", [
  Validators.required,
  Validators.min(1),
])
```

This way you will be able to adjust the strings via input and will get a result array as following: `["de","en"]`.